# urlrewritingnet - Keep original URL hidden from user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

My raw page Url is like this

```
http://mydomain/product-list?Type=AllProducts&ListCategory=Category&ListCriteria=All&KeyWord=109
```

How i want this URL to be visible for user is like this

```
http://mydomain/product-list/FURNITURE-HOUSE?Type=AllProducts&ListCategory=Category&ListCriteria=All&KeyWord=109
```

So I wrote a `urlrewritingnet` Rule like this

```
    <add name="produktidrewrite"
     virtualUrl="^~/product-list/(.*)"
     rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     destinationUrl="~/product-list"
     redirect="Application"
     redirectMode="Permanent"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

This works like when ever I enter this url in browser

```
http://mydomain/product-list/FURNITURE-HOUSE?Type=AllProducts&ListCategory=Category&ListCriteria=All&KeyWord=109
```

it is rewritten to

```
http://mydomain/product-list?Type=AllProducts&ListCategory=Category&ListCriteria=All&KeyWord=109
```

as you can see category name is gone from the URL. how can I overcome this? And make sure that user also see a URL like this

```
http://mydomain/product-list/FURNITURE-HOUSE?Type=AllProducts&ListCategory=Category&ListCriteria=All&KeyWord=109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what you mean is custom routing on .NET MVC,
you actually could do that using attribute route something like this on your Controller Action Method :

```
[Route(“{productId:int}/{productTitle}”)]
public ActionResult Show(int productId) { … }
```

or you can see better on this link : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

CMIWW